# Redux-Thunk - Async action creators Promise and chaining not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise

I am trying to dispatch an action. I found working examples for some actions, but not as complex as mine.

Would you give me a hint? What am I doing wrong?

I am using TypeScript and have recently removed all typings and simplified my code as much as possible.

I am using redux-thunk and redux-promise, like this:

```
import { save } from 'redux-localstorage-simple';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';

const middlewares = [
        save(),
        thunkMiddleware,
        promiseMiddleware,
    ];
const store = createStore(
        rootReducer(appReducer),
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
            window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__'] ? window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__']() : f => f,
        ),
    );
```

**Component - Foo Component:**

```
import actionFoo from 'js/actions/actionFoo';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Foo {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    _handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.doActionFoo().then(() => {
            // this.props.doActionFoo returns undefined
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <div onClick={this._handleSubmit}/>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({}) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    doActionFoo: actionFoo,
};

export { Foo as PureComponent };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);
```

**Action - actionFoo:**

```
export default () => authCall({
    types: ['REQUEST', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILURE'],
    endpoint: `/route/foo/bar`,
    method: 'POST',
    shouldFetch: state => true,
    body: {},
});
```

**Action - AuthCall:**

```
// extremly simplified
export default (options) => (dispatch, getState) => dispatch(apiCall(options));
```

**Action - ApiCall:**

```
export default (options) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { endpoint, shouldFetch, types } = options;

    if (shouldFetch && !shouldFetch(getState())) return Promise.resolve();

    let response;
    let payload;

    dispatch({
        type: types[0],
    });

    return fetch(endpoint, options)
        .then((res) => {
            response = res;
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
            payload = json;

            if (response.ok) {
                return dispatch({
                    response,
                    type: types[1],
                });
            }
            return dispatch({
                response,
                type: types[2],
            });
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch({
            response,
            type: types[2],
        }));
};
```

Comment: what does `console.log(res.json())` return?

Comment: It's a Promise. A resolved one

Comment: Does your debugger tell you which `then` is being called on `undefined`?

Comment: It's been a while since i've used redux thunk and i'm not sure but my guess is that actionFoo should return a dispatch call instead of a direct call to the authCall action.

Maybe this example (which a wrote long ago) can help you: https://github.com/svenvandescheur/react-redux-consumerjs-example/

Comment: @JoshuaR. Sure, the one: this.props.doActionFoo(gameName, password).then() I have commented in code above

Comment: Do you have `redux-promise`? `redux-thunk` doesnt handle promises

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur: No, because above is the short form of:

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        doActionFoo: () => dispatch(actionFoo()),
    };
};

Comment: @TheReason: I thought redux-thunk is handling this for me: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: I do not need to try this, because arrow functions automatically return the next statement, if there is no block scope starting

Comment: `AuthCall` is returning dispatch which does not return a promise. I don't follow why `AuthCall` needs to call `dispatch()` with `ApiCall` nested inside, if `ApiCall` calls dispatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after several hours, I found a solution. redux-thunk had to go first before any other middleware. Because middleware is called from right to left, redux-thunk return is last in chain and therefore returns the Promise.

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [
        thunkMiddleware,
        // ANY OTHER MIDDLEWARE,
    ];
const store = createStore(
        rootReducer(appReducer),
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
            window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__'] ? window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__']() : f => f,
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

From [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return
>   a function instead of an action

So it means that it doesn't handle your promises. You have to add [`redux-promise`](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) for promise supporting

> The default export is a middleware function. If it receives a promise,
>   it will dispatch the resolved value of the promise. It will not
>   dispatch anything if the promise rejects.

The differences between `redux-thunk` vs `redux-promise` you can read [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577510/what-is-the-difference-between-redux-thunk-and-redux-promise)

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to add this to my existing code, or do I only need to add this to middlewares?

Comment: @dazlious just add it your middlewares

Comment: Before or after thunk is added?

Comment: do you have any working example with connect and mapDispatchToProps? I can not get this working

Comment: Okay, then what am I doing wrong? :( This is upsetting ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162593/discussion-between-the-reason-and-dazlious).